# TextBlob translator cannot detect the different language in dataframe

Tags: python, nlp

I run the language translator using TextBlob. It can translate from a string. However, I tried to loop the textblob translator for the data in a dataframe which in dataframe might have a mixed of different languages (en and es).

The code I used is :

```py
for content in data:
  blob = TextBlob(content)

for i in data:
  blob = TextBlob(i)

blob.translate(from_lang = 'en', to = 'es')
```

The error is :

```
    83             result = result.encode('utf-8')
    84         if result.strip() == source.strip():
---> 85             raise NotTranslated('Translation API returned the input string unchanged.')
    86 
    87     def _request(self, url, host=None, type_=None, data=None):

NotTranslated: Translation API returned the input string unchanged.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is not necessary in each case that 'en' and 'es' must be different. There can be many cases in which 'es' and 'en' have the same text. So the error is being raised in the case where both of them are same. Using the try and catch statement will tackle all the cases having same texts eventually making your code to work.

```py
for content in data:
  blob = TextBlob(content)

for i in data:
  blob = TextBlob(i)
  try:
     print (blob.translate(from_lang = 'en', to = 'es'))
  except:
     print ("Same translation so skipping")
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But the output is 'Same translation so skipping' for some reasons, perhaps because there is same language in a row in dataframe. How to print the result to see overall translated data in overall row?

Comment: I cannot understand what you are trying to say but try now. Hope so it answers your query.